# Material and construction properties of drive shafts, wheel shafts, gearbox

Tags: transmission, drivetrain

I am looking for some typical properties of a 1.4L rear-drive car's drive shaft, drive-wheel shafts and the gearbox. I need to calculate the moment of inertia of the components of the drive-train. So i am looking for dimensions and material of the drive train components of a typical car. Also the transmission ratio of the pinion-drive shaft would be useful.

These data will be just a small part of a thesis on the vibration control, so i wish i could find them easy. Thanks in advance.

Vaggelis K.

Comment: So you are asking us to help your write your thesis? I don't think there will be any "typical" information here. First of all, there are only a handful of vehicles which utilize a rear-engine design (Porsche being the most prevalent). This information would be as easy for you to look up as it would be for us ...

Comment: I am not expecting from anyone to look up for anything. I am asking just in case someone else had already collected similar data. If you had for example the length-inner diameter-outer diameter of a drive shaft, it would be a great help for me to have them. You shouldn't be ironic. It is just a data that i need to calculate the resonant frequency in torsional vibration. Moment of inertia and torsional stiffness are inputs in a matlab code. I am going to make a phone call in Porche to get my typical information.

Answer (score 2):

Manufacturing cars is a commercial enterprise. Cars are built with very wide criteria to arrive at a finished product. Materials used, dimensions and the such like would be arrived at after expensive design and testing proceedures. To complicate matters you have a situation where there is no such thing as a typical car or component, even they may do the same job. Typical materials, say steel, can be alloyed and treated to various processes to produce a steel with a desired property. This then would cascade into the realms of dimensions, machining requirements, costs and a myriad of other considerations. The information you require would really be 'trade secrets' and are extremely unlikely to be in any public domain.